# Coupon / promo code solutions (gem) for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to implement coupons, promos and gifts into an app, however I'm not seeing a satisfactory gem as of yet.  It can't be spree specific as I've seen some like this.  Are there any well implemented and tested solutions already floating around that I'm missing?

Comment: It seems like it would be something app-specific. Can you provide more info?

Comment: Well, for example, take a look at GoDaddy.  They accept a coupon code on checkout.  Likewise most shopping carts today support some kind of a discount code entry mechanism.  This is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [coupons](https://github.com/fnando/coupons) gem for implementing discount codes.